# How to use DateRangePicker on C# Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, daterangepicker

I'm having trouble on how to implement a date range picker on a C# Razor Page. I've seen some examples for singular date pickers (like picking one date), but not much for date ranges.

So the page I'm working on uses HTML Helpers. It gets it's properties from this class/model:

```
public class Appointment{
  [Display(Name = "Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(..., ..., FormMethod.Get, ...){

  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
  </div>
  <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
  </div>

  -- the date range input field would be below the above input field, but I'm confused how to use the Html Helper for the two dates for the singular daterangepicker input field
}
```

The JavaScript example code for the daterangepicker is from this [site](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4), and looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

Basically I'm confused on how a singular input field is going to map to both StartDate and EndDate. I see that TextBoxFor accepts one property, but not sure how you would handle more than that.

Comment: From that page, it seems that it produces a text field with a string value containing the both dates

Comment: @Lockszmith so would you map what you get from that input field to a string, and then later split it up to two DateTime properties? Wasn't sure if that was the best way or if there was something more straight forward.

Comment: When you select data in daterangepicker, you want to bind that value to StartDate  and EndDate in your model?

Answer (score 1):

This Javascript will generate a text about the Date range, In my opinion, you can add some code to bind value to your datetime in model, Please refer to this demo.

**PageModel**

```
[BindProperty]
public Appointment appointment { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<form asp-action="Privacy" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="appointment.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="appointment.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input asp-for="appointment.StartDate" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="appointment.EndDate" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
   
    <hr />

    <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Javscript**

```
function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

                // add this code to bind value.
                var s = start.toJSON();
                var e = end.toJSON();

                $('#appointment_StartDate').val(s);
                $('#appointment_EndDate').val(e);
    }
```

**Demo:**
[image]

Comment: Hi @oturan, if this answer can help you solve this issue, could you accept it as answer? Thank you so much.